# Have two servers running on Google VM

Tags: linux

I have managed to have my python server up and running on Google's VM.

However, is it possible to have another server running on the same instance?

My first server runs on a specific port. Theoretically, there is no restriction on having another server on the system, running on a different port.
I can do this on my "real" pc, with two different terminal instances.

However, the terminal that i get with Google VM, is single. Therefore, when i run the python server, my terminal is occupied. So is it possible to start another terminal session, in order to start another server?

EDIT:
I am having trouble sending the process to the background.
This is the output of jobs:

```
$ jobs
[1]-  Stopped                 sudo docker run -p 5001:5001 -it -v $(pwd):/mnt/translation -w="/mnt/translation" -e 
"TERM=xterm-color" f_translate
[2]+  Stopped                 sudo docker run -p 5001:5001 -it -v $(pwd):/mnt/translation -w="/mnt/translation" -e 
"TERM=xterm-color" f_translate`enter code here`
```

And when i try to run the command normally (it fails and it not enter the docker container):

```
$ sudo docker run -p 5001:5001 -it -v $(pwd):/mnt/translation -w=
"/mnt/translation" -e "TERM=xterm-color" f_translate &
[3] 23072
$ ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you are running Linux VM. In this case this is not GCP specific question, but Linux in general.

There are several ways you can achieve what you want:

1. Run a command with `&` and `disown`. `&` runs command in background, and `disown` prevents it from stopping when you disconnect session

```
<command> &
disown
```

2. Run a command with `nohup`. `nohup` bypasses the HUP signal (signal hang up), making it possible to run commands in the background even when the terminal is off.

```
nohup <command> &
```

3. Turn it into a [service](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6)
4. Use [terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer)

---

### EDIT

Containers are a completely different beast, and I highly recommend you read a [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/).
You are trying to start a container *and* attach to it with `-it` *and* start it in background. While this will *kinda* work, it's not the right way to do this.
To start a container in the background you should run it in detached mode with `-d` option:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5001:5001 -v $(pwd):/mnt/translation -w="/mnt/translation" -e "TERM=xterm-color" f_translate
```

*notice `-d` after `run`, and no `-it` option*

then, if you need, you can attach to it with

```
docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/bash
```

and detach with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! I really like the first approach. But in my case, i kill a server with `Control+C`. If i use the first method, since it is in the background, the only way to kill it is finding its pid and using `pkill`?

Comment: Yes. You can also find tasks running in the background with `jobs`. Then `fg <job-id>` to bring it to the foreground and `control+c` to stop it.

Comment: Thank you once again. I am having some problems, that i cannot figure them out. Do you happen to understand what is going on? I updated the question.

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer, see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! One more question i have. When i start a normal web server in Google vm. And i leave my pc (i close the terminal) but i want the process still running. Will just running the server work? Or do i always have to `disown` before i close the terminal?

Comment: I tried your command but it did not work. When i typed it, i get back a string `9f8cc86f1e4a262bff8ff4f40f1a9036c686472b0ec3fded84980a60d26f6980`. However, i cannot attach to the running container later. I typed `sudo docker ps` and there are no running containers.

Comment: That string is container id, it means the container was created. What happened was, probably, an application inside have stopped, and so container was stopped. Explaining how containers work seems outside of the scope of this question. 
Just know this - containers exists as long as application inside is running.

Answer (score 1):

> So is it possible to start another terminal session, in order to start another server?

Yes - applications that allow running multiple terminal sessions within one terminal session are called "terminal multiplexers". Learning and using one of the most popular ones - `tmux` `screen` (`byobu`) - will be a valuable experience.